# Using PostGIS to find which county in California has most settlements in forest?

Tags: postgis, sql

Using PostGIS how do I find which county in California has the most settlements in the forest?
I have point settlements `settlements_CA`, polygon forests `forests_CA` and polygon counties `counties_CA` in PostGIS Database.
I tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(st.*) as count, ct.name
FROM settlements_CA AS st, forests_CA as fo, counties_CA AS ct
WHERE
ST_Contains(fo.geom, st.the_geom)
GROUP BY ct.name
ORDER BY ct.name
;
```

this query was very slow and the result is wrong because it reports that all counties have the same numbers of settlements.

I also tried `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` but failed.

Comment: I would try to do 2 iterations 1) Select locations (points) that fall into the forests; 2) From the result of the first iteration, select localities that fall into the counties and count their maximum number in each county

Comment: Do you have a lookup between counties and settlements? If they are in separate tables, this is why you are getting the wrong answer, as your spatial join in on forests and settlements, and there is nothing to link counties to settlements. So, you either need a 2nd spatial query as in @RoVo's answer, or you need to do a join by attribute, eg, settlement to counties. Also, as regards this being slow, make sure you have a spatial index on the columns involved in the contains.

Comment: Also, it is often helpful to show an EXPLAIN statement, as concepts like big and slow are somewhat meaningless out of context. I have queries that run from anything from 1ms to 2 days -- it just depends what they are doing.

Comment: @Cyril The idea of ​​your decomposition task is very inspiring to me.

Comment: @JohnPowell You have indicated in principle where the mistake is, I am very benefiting. The answer of @RoVo's 2nd join seems to be correct, but what you mean of `join by attribute, eg, settlement to counties`?

Comment: @JohnPowell the suggestions of building spatial index and using `EXPLAIN` statement are helpful for me to work on big and slow things.

Comment: 1) Try to choose a simple and correct solution; 2) You accepted the answer, so the proposed method allows you to solve a similar problem; 3) John Powell is a professional in his field, I’m sure of it, he just wants you to work a little, don’t you: -) ...

Comment: @Cyril yeah, I should learn more about how to fishing, not just accept and pick the fish.

Comment: Well, then we will try to catch it differently, because the Indians of America do it ... I hope that you have a sense of humor: -) ...

Comment: @Cyril, ha, ha, well I try to be professional. I meant that you might have a lookup table between settlements and counties, and so, you would not need to do a 2nd spatial join, as in Rovo's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing to join the result from `ST_Contains(fo.geom, st.the_geom)` with the counties. I'd do a subselect as it's better to read.

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(ct.name) as count, ct.name
FROM counties_CA AS ct

JOIN
(
  SELECT st.the_geom
  FROM settlements_CA AS st
  JOIN forests_CA as fo
  ON ST_Contains(fo.geom, st.the_geom)
) as st_in_fo
ON st_intersects(ct.the_geom, st_in_fo.the_geom)

GROUP BY ct.name
;
```

As for the performance, you will need to have indexes on all `the_geom` columns.

Comment: What RoVo says, unless you have a lookup between county and settlement, in which case, you can do the 2nd join on that.